# How to use hsl custom color in tailwind in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to use this given below colors as regular using `arbitrary-values` in `className` of **ul** in react:

```
- Soft orange: hsl(35, 77%, 62%)
- Soft red: hsl(5, 85%, 63%)
```

Here's some current snippets below:

- tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
    theme: {
        colors: {
            'orange': 'hsl(35, 77%, 62%)',
            'red': 'hsl(5, 85%, 63%)'
        }

    },
    plugins: []
};
```

- App.js

```
<ul className="flex font-['Inter-Regular'] hover:text-[color:hsl(35, 77%, 62%)] flex-row items-center"> ...

</ul>
```

- index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

//...
```

I got only one [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75147330/how-to-use-custom-css-colors-in-my-tailwind-preset) but that doesn't work for me!

I am looking to use `hsl()` in className of `ul` as an arbitrary value without installing any dependencies.

and please make sure i dont want to convert it in any format.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces delimit class names, so the class `hover:text-[color:hsl(35, 77%, 62%)]` would be actually three different classes, `hover:text-[color:hsl(35,`, `77%,` and `62%)]`.

To work around this, you can remove the spaces like `hover:text-[color:hsl(35,77%,62%)]` or [use underscores to "escape" spaces](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content#using-spaces-and-underscores) like `hover:text-[color:hsl(35,_77%,_62%)]`.